# Setting the default state after fetching the product returns undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to set default states for color, size, etc. when I dispatch the `getProduct(id)` action, I get the product and everything is fine (my product has a size in it: `size: ['s','m'...]`). I want it to be the first element in the array by default, i do something like this:

```
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { product, isLoading } = useSelector(state => state.product);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProduct(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);


  const [sizeState, setSizeState] = useState(
    product?.size?.length > 0 && product?.size[0]
  );
```

`console.log(product?.size?.length` > 0 returns false `console.log(product?.size[0])` returns undefined.

This is my product object:
[Product object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNLRn.png)

Comment: Where is the console.log in your code?

Comment: After const [sizeState, setSizeState] = useState(
    product?.size?.length > 0 && product?.size[0]
  );

Answer (score 0):

Just add useEffect observer for product state. and then use unshift method of array

```
useEffect(()=>{

if(product){


setSize((prevState)=>[product?.size,...prevState])
}

},[product])
```

Comment: I got TypeError: prevState is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you didn't parse the JSON object after fetching the product. Make sure to parse it after fetching.

```
fetch(URL, OPTIONS).then(res => res.json());
```